# Playframework: override BadRequest

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using Playframework 2.0 (scala version) and I want to override "BadRequest" method in one of my controllers.
My controller extends a trait:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.libs.json.JsObject

/*
 * Simple trait to factor common code used by all controllers...
 */
trait AbstractController extends Controller {
 // Personal useful methods
 // ...
 // Implementation of an override of BadRequest ?
}
```

My controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise

object MyController extends AbstractController
{

 def myFunc (s: String) = {
    BadRequest(s) // should return what I'll define in MY BadRequest implementation
  }
}
```

What I want to do: implement a new comportment of BadRequest (i.e. return a JSON with error details) *only* for controllers extending AbstractController.
Play documentation suggest doing that in Global Object (extends GlobalSettings) and override onBadRequest method. But I do not want a so global method... only in specific controllers.

What is the best solution?

Thanks for your help.
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see what the problem is here. What is wrong with just overriding it?

```
trait AbstractController extends Controller {
  override val BadRequest = ... 

}
```

Comment: Kim, you're right, I made a mistake: use *def* instead of *val*.