# overrideing BadRequest play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Playframework 2.3.x and I want to override `BadRequest` method in one of my controllers. I have exact same requirement as shown in seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724281/playframework-override-badrequest) thread but not sure if it's to do with answer that doesn't look complete in that thread or I am not able to find BadRequest parent impl to be able to corretly override `BadRequest`

have a `BaseController` which all other controllers `extend`. I want to `override` `BadRequest` in `BaseController` such that all controllers (which extend `BaseController`) can do

```
def myMethod (s: String) = {
BadRequest(s) // should return what I'll define in MY BadRequest implementation in `BaseController`
}
```

`BaseController` I want to override `BadRequest` such that when above method passes in `s:String` it'll convert it to Json something like

```
 override val BadRequest(msg:String) = Json.toJson(msg) //of course this doesn't complie
```

Comment: @m-z : updated question with more details. let me know.

Comment: Don't have time to write more details at the moment, but give this a try: `def BadRequest(msg: String): Result = BadRequest(Json.toJson(msg))`  (it compiles for me, but I'm not sure how it will behave)

Comment: @m-z that's not overriding it. you are creating a new `def` parent has `val`

Comment: You can't override the val and give it parameters though.

Comment: @m-z : yes, that's exactly what my question is about since you can't override `val` how do you override `BadRequst` if at all?

Comment: Did you even try my suggestion? What I'm saying is you **don't have to override the val**, because you can't override it with a def. But if you define the def as I did in my comment, the controllers will use that instead (when the signature matches). And the whole reason this works is because `BadRequest(msg)` has a different signature.

Comment: @m-z : you're right actually. My bad I was overlooking creating new method and was concentrating on `override` keyword a lot. sorry for the back & forth. it does work that way. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the implementation of BadRequest [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/a38d8d126ad137afaac127400f3ff4df32fc11cc/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L640).  Note that BadRequest is a val and has type `Status`. The implementation of the `Status` class has an `apply` function that allows for String parameters. Since BadRequest is a val, it can only be overridden with another val of type `Status`, so I don't think you can override BadRequest the way you want to here.  Is there a reason you can't define it under a different name?

```
def MyBadRequest(msg:String) = BadRequest(Json.toJson(msg))
```